# Reading code without running it

Tags: c

So I have this code that I'm trying to figure out how to read without running it yet I can't seem to find out the pattern and the way to do so. I was hoping someone could give me an explanation of how to read it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mystery(int z[], int size);

void main()

{
    int i;
    int z[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d", z[i]);
    printf("\n\n");

    mystery(z, 10);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d", z[i]);
    printf("\n\n");

    mystery(z, 7);

    for (i = 10; i < 7; i++)
        printf("%d", z[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
}

void mystery(int z[], int n)
{
    int i, temp;

    for (i = 1; i < n / 2; i = i + 2)
    {
        temp = z[i];
        z[i] = z[n - 1 - i];
        z[n - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
    return;
}
```

When running it, the code reads

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 9 3 7 5 6 4 8 2 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that you understand this loop:

```
for (i = 1; i < n / 2; i = i + 2)
    {
        temp = z[i];
        z[i] = z[n - 1 - i];
        z[n - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
```

`i + 2` means the step (the increment). The step is 2 rather than 1 in this case which means that `i` will increase like 1, 3, 5, 7... up to n / 2. The content of the loop just switches the outer elements of the bounds i.e. the first iteration the elements 2 and 9 will switch places.

Because the start of the loop is `i=1`(and not `i=0`) the first element is not affected by the loop. Remember arrays start at 0, so the second element has index 1 and that's where the loop starts: At the second element. And since the step is 2, only every second element will switch. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: How do I know what n is?

Comment: n is set to be 10 in your program, if you look at the invocation it says the number 10=n.

Comment: I'm still having trouble, sorry, so for example, if I start with i = 1. Would the equation be z[1] = [10 -1 - 8]  and so 1 = 1, or for i = 2, would it be z[2] = z[10 - 1 - 0] and therefore 2 = 9? Thanks again.

Comment: Almost! For `i=1`,  `z[i] = z[10 -1 - 1]=z[8]` so the 2nd element will get the value of the ninth element. For `i=2`, `z[i]=z[10-1-2]=z[7]` whereupon the 3rd and 8th element will switch and so on. Remember that index starts with 0 and not 1.

Comment: Thank you very much! Last question, sorry haha, so why does 1 = 1 and not 1 = 10? Same with 3 = 3 and not being 3 = 8 and so on

Comment: Because the start of the loop is `i=1`(and not `i=0`). Remember arrays start at 0, so the second element has index 1 and that's where the loop starts: At the second element. And since the step is 2, only every second element will switch. I hope this answers your question.